# Excel VBA: Sequential numbers + specified start will increment upto end values + shift column data down

Tags: excel, vba

Im new to this VBA thing can someone help to add sequence on a specified value.
[image: Output should be like this]

here is the code I get one of the conversation here.

```
Sub sof20143262Serial_numbers()

    Dim i, iStep, j, jp1, startNumber, endNumber, delta
    Dim bEmpty As Boolean
    Dim strRange

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    bEmpty = False
    j = 2

    jp1: j + 1
    strRange : range name

    Do While (Not bEmpty)
        jp1 = j + 1
        strRange = "A" & j

        startNumber = Range(strRange).Value
        endNumber = Range("B" & j).Value
        bEmpty = IsEmpty(startNumber)

        If (bEmpty) Then
            Exit Do
        End If

        delta = endNumber - startNumber
        If (endNumber < startNumber) Then
            iStep = 1
            delta = -delta
        Else
            iStep = -1
        End If

        Range("C" & j).Value = startNumber
        endNumber = endNumber + iStep

        For i = endNumber To startNumber Step iStep
            Range(strRange).Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
            Range("C" & jp1).Value = i - iStep
            Range("D" & jp1 & ":" & "E" & jp1).Value = Range("D" & j & ":" & "E" & j).Value
        Next
        '
        '   prepare the next loop:
        '
        j = j + delta + 1
        '
    Loop
    '
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see big differences between your original code and what I produced. But the following code produces what you have in your picture except that it moves the Start and End numbers with the insertions. That could be avoided, of course, but it would take a bit more coding.

```
Option Explicit

Enum Nws                            ' Rows & Columns
    NwsFirstDataRow = 2             ' = 1 caption row (adjust as required)
    NwsStart = 1                    ' 1 = column A (adjust as required)
    NwsEnd                          ' no value = previous + 1
    NwsSerial
End Enum

Sub SerialNumbers()
    ' 06 Apr 2017

    Dim Series As Long              ' = Start
    Dim Repeats As Integer          ' = End
    Dim R As Long                   ' row number
    Dim i As Integer                ' repeat counter

    R = NwsFirstDataRow
    With ActiveSheet
        Series = Val(.Cells(R, NwsStart).Value)
        Repeats = Val(.Cells(R, NwsEnd).Value)
        If Repeats Then
            Do While Series > 0
                For i = 1 To Repeats
                    If i > 1 Then
                        R = R + 1
                        .Rows(R).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlUp
                    End If
                    .Cells(R, NwsSerial).Value = Series * 10 + i
                Next i
                R = R + 1
                Series = Val(.Cells(R, NwsStart).Value)
            Loop
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Yey it works! It helps a lot bro! Thank you very much for helping me!

Comment: Of it does what you want, accept the answer as a guide to others. I'm glad it worked for you.

Comment: Hi Sir another question, the last sequence that end with zero are converting or or automatically round off the next digit that included on that zero sequence. Sample 12340 then it came out like this

12341
12342
12343
12344
12345
12346
12347
12348
12349
12350

can you help with this? Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Another question, by definition, is another question - all the more so since I don't understand what you mean. 12341, rounded, would give you 12340 which is the same result you would have from 12342. 12345 to 12350 would all return 12350. Is it that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

This picture of your final result didn't upload correctly and your code isn't self-explanatory in all respects. However, I tried to divine what is intended and amended your code to what I think it might look like when finished. Here it is.

```
Sub sof20143262Serial_numbers()

    Dim i As Long, iStep As Long
    Dim R As Long, jp1 As Long
    Dim startNumber As Long, endNumber As Long, delta As Long
    Dim bEmpty As Boolean
'    Dim strRange

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'    bEmpty = False
    R = 2
'    jp1: R + 1 strRange : range name

    With ActiveSheet
        Do While Len(.Cells(R, 1).Value)
    '        jp1 = R + 1
    '        strRange = "A" & R
        startNumber = Cells(R, 1).Value
'        startNumber = Range(strRange).Value
'        endNumber = Range("B" & R).Value
        endNumber = Cells(R, 2).Value

'        bEmpty = IsEmpty(startNumber)
'        If (bEmpty) Then
'            Exit Do
'        End If

        delta = Abs(endNumber - startNumber)
        iStep = IIf(endNumber < startNumber, 1, -1)
'        delta = endNumber - startNumber
'        If (endNumber < startNumber) Then
'            iStep = 1
'            delta = delta * -1
'        Else
'            iStep = -1
'        End If

        .Cells(R, 3).Value = startNumber
'        Range("C" & R).Value = startNumber
        endNumber = endNumber + iStep

        For i = endNumber To startNumber Step iStep
'            Range(strRange).Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
            .Rows(R).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlUp
            R = R + 1
            .Cells(R, "C").Value = i - iStep
            .Cells(R, "D").Value = .Cells(R - 1, "D").Value
            .Cells(R, "E").Value = .Cells(R - 1, "E").Value
'            Range("C" & jp1).Value = i - iStep
'            Range("D" & jp1 & ":" & "E" & jp1).Value = Range("D" & R & ":" & "E" & R).Value
        Next
    End With

            ' prepare the next loop:
'            R = R + delta + 1
            R = R + 1
         Loop
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I have kept most of your code in place so that you can find your way about. Many of your ideas I have implemented differently. I hope that you will appreciate the intention and even correct my code where it may fail because, for lack of data, the entire thing was never tried.

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: How can i post my image here? so you can see my output should be. :( and also so you can see my codes output. by the way appreciated your code.